# OBIEE and ODI on the same Weblogic Server

Tags: oracle11g, obiee, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-bi

Can I run OBIEE and ODI (all 11G) on the same weblogic server on

1. Different Domains
2. Same Domain, different Managed Servers.

If yes, then please give me some pointers/start.

Thanks
Angad

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, using two managed servers. OBI Apps actually uses that setup.

However, I wouldn't recommend it. You might upgrade each product at different times so supported versions of weblogic might not be aligned at some point.

You might also have a licensing issue, as the weblogic license which comes with OBIEE is restricted to the use of OBIEE.